# ios, facebook and getting profile image

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to get profile image of facebook friends. I know I can do this in code by getting id of user and using this link: userID/picture">http://graph.facebook.com/*userID*/picture. Is there easier way to get profile image directly from facebook sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about getting the url of the profile picture? then use something like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to display the image and cache it to device. or any open source library that can display and cache image just by passing the url to it?

then, get the userIDs of his friends. save them in NSArray. then create a fql.

```
-(void)getFriendsInfo:(NSArray*)userIDs
{
    //prepare param
    NSMutableString *paramStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
       for (int i = 0; i<[userIDs count]; i++) {
        if ([[userIDs objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        NSString *tempParam = [NSString stringWithString:[[userIDs objectAtIndex:i]stringValue]];
        [paramStr appendFormat:@"'%@',", tempParam];
    }
}
    [paramStr appendFormat:@"%@",@"'9999999999999'"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (%@)", tempParam], @"query",
                               nil];

    //in my case, I declared  Facebook *facebook; in my app delegate using the latest fb sdk
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                 andParams:params
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
}
```

handle the data in delegate method

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook SDK uses the same user ID and path to its graph. So I think it is not easier. But the same.