# How to get face book contacts(email-id's) of friends for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am new to iphone, am trying to get the email-id's of friends from my face book account. I need to

save this contact info into my application and display in a UItableview . I am using graph api, using

this am able to get the friend's list,feeds metadata etc. But i want to fetch the contact info of all

my added friends. This is my code to fetch the friends list:

```
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
    NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

Comment: check this  post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667937/ios-facebook-and-getting-profile-image  the OP is asking for the url of profile picture, you want email address, Im not sure if you can get it using fql but you might want to give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph API me/friends will return you the list of friends which only has the friend's user ID and full name. As far as I know, it's not possible for you to retrieve your friends' email from an iPhone application.

And it looks like you're using the old library, try to download the latest FacebookConnect library from github. It's much simpler to use.